# charAt(i) is not giving expecting Behaviour with arrays

Tags: java

Below is my simple program which converts a string into elements of array, `charAt(i)` is not returning what it is supposed to according to documentation. My code is

```
public class StringToArray {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String test = "12345";
        fromPuzzleString(test);
    }

    public static void fromPuzzleString(String puzzle) {
        int puz[] = new int[puzzle.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < puzzle.length(); i++) {
            puz[i] = puzzle.charAt(i);
        }
        for (int c : puz) {
            System.out.println(c);

        }
    }
}
```

Expected output: `1 2 3 4 5`

Real output: `49 50 51 52 53`

but when i use puz[i] = puzzle.charAt(i)-"O"; 
 its working Fine..!

Comment: It's 0 (zero) what you use and not O. You just discovered the feature of the ASCII, UTF-8 and other code tables, that the numbers follow each other starting with 0. That's why your code showed at the end works. @Reimeus's solution avoid such preconceptions, although probably it'll be always true.

Answer (score 4):

You are displaying the character's unicode point values. Instead, you could use

```
System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue(c));
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because a character's value is not the same as the `int` used to represent it. Declaring `puz` as a `char[]` should resolve the issue and print the numbers as expected.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
    char puz[] = new char[puzzle.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < puzzle.length(); i++) {
        puz[i] = puzzle.charAt(i);
    }
    for (char c : puz) {
        System.out.println(c);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Its normal.

You take the string "1" not the number 1.
To get the number, prefer use Integer.paserInt(yourString);
then you'l lget your number.

As example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String test = "12345";
        fromPuzzleString(test);
    }

    public static void fromPuzzleString(String puzzle) {
        int puz[] = new int[puzzle.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < puzzle.length(); i++) {
            puz[i] = Integer.parseInt(puzzle.charAt(i));
        }
        for (int c : puz) {
            System.out.println(c);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're casting the char you get to an int, thus Java will print its integer representation. Store the result as an array of Strings, and loop over that array to print.

Answer (score 0):

You implicitly convert `char` to `int`,a char '1' is not equals to 1,You can cast them to char  like:

```
 System.out.println((char)c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the int array so it prints the ascii values.You can do the following  :

```
public static void fromPuzzleString(String puzzle) {    
    for (int i = 0; i < puzzle.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println( puzzle.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

You need not use 2 for loops and an array unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

`"charAt(i) is not returning what it is supposed to according to documentation"`

You cannot put a `char` inside an `int`. Or else it will return its **unicode** value.

The values returned `Real output: 49 50 51 52 53` are the unicode **[ASCII Characters codes](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)**

This will solve your issue:

```
public class StringToArray {

        public static void main(String[] args){
            String test = "12345";
            fromPuzzleString(test);
        }

        public static void fromPuzzleString(String puzzle) {
            char[] puz = new char[puzzle.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < puzzle.length(); i++) {
                puz[i] = puzzle.charAt(i);
            }
            for (char c : puz) {
                System.out.println(c);

            }
        }
    }
```

However, to save memory I would suggest that you do not declare an array, display the values immediately like this:

```
public class StringToArray {

        public static void main(String[] args){
            String test = "12345";
            fromPuzzleString(test);
        }

        public static void fromPuzzleString(String puzzle) {
           for (int i = 0; i < puzzle.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println(puzzle.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you all for explaining this issue to me... it worked perfectly... But while looking for an explanation i came up with something which still confuses me(Please see Edited Question), any help with this is much appreciated

Comment: Opps my mistake... Its not "0" its "O"(with ASCII value of 48)... it solved my problem without any major Restructuring... Once again Thanx

Comment: It will solve your problem only if you're using digits in your string. As 0 having ASCII value 48 is a reference for the digits, when you substract it you're substracting the ASCII value which is 48( btw it's '0' and not "0" in your edited questions). I recommend that you use the way I provided. It's more general, less complex and straight forward.